# How can I click second button on one webpage using selenium python3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

Working in python, selenium, Win 7, I want to click on `sowcomment` button after it is able to clickable that is located on this [webPage](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2016/07/generals-resign-turkey-military-council-160728055057094.html), handled by `wait` then I want to click on `showmore Comments` button to see more comments in order to scrape more comments. After first button, i am able to extract comments.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as UI

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2016/07/erdogan-west-mind-business-160729205425215.html")
wait = UI.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
next_page_link = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'showcomment')))
next_page_link.click()

wait = UI.WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
next_page_link2 = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Show more comments')))
next_page_link2.click()

v = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gig-comment-body')
print(v)
for h in v:
    print(h.text)
```

but second button is unable to click rather giving the exception:

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:

What is the problem?

Comment: Could you share HTML for this link here?? Or did you tried some other locators?? Or try using `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur For HTML, I gave link above you can go to. I tried other selectors too but all in vain.

Comment: I'm not able to see the HTML by given your link this time, because I'm not with PC that's why I'm telling you Share here that link HTML..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur `http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2016/07/generals-resign-turkey-military-council-160728055057094.html`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using `execute_script()` to perform click as below :

```
next_page_link2 = wait.until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(),"Show more comments")]')))

#now click this using execute_script
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", next_page_link2)
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: @Saurah Gaur . Noope.

Comment: @Ali is there any exception??

Comment: @Saurah Gaur . Same exception: `Element is not clickable at point (546.9833374023438, 23.850006103515625)`

Comment: @Ali you are using `.click()` that's this occurs, please try to click using `execute_script` as I provided in second line...

Comment: Yeah ! I am using `execute script`.

Comment: I was using `chromewebdriver` , I switched to `FireFox` and then it is working. Why is that?

Comment: @Ali if you are using this exception will never occur... I think you are clicking first using .click() then going to execute... please omit .click() before execute_script

Comment: @Ali Yeah it's mostly occurs on chrome browser due to overlay of other elements..it's a browser issue but you can perform it using JavaScript on chrome..:)

Comment: No! `javascript` is not working on the chrome. As you suggested `execute`